# Rundeck Vs Jenkins for better scheduling of jobs

Tags: jenkins, rundeck

We are creating performance framework so it would involve scheduling of jobs with delays(also running a job with custom conditions) and also running multiple jobs in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

There is very little context from your question. I will give you an overview.

From performance point of view, there isn't much difference, Jenkins and Rundeck are both Java based.

You will have a lot more flexibility with Jenkins.

From my own pass experience, people from development background love Jenkins, while people from operations, sysadmin background tend to choose Rundeck.

There is an article wrote by Damon Edwards on Rundeck news, it may not answer your question, but it is worth to have a look.
[Jenkins is for Development. Rundeck is for Operations](http://rundeck.org/news/2014/01/08/Jenkins-is-for-development-Rundeck-is-for-operations.html)

Comment: People from ops choose bash terminal and saltstack :)

Comment: I'm liking Jenkins seeming robustness though,   we put Jenkins and Salt master together in the same container,  salt minions used for remote tasks.   Salt minions are 10 times smaller footprint than jenkins agents plus you get all that stuff with minions.